# C# sort out 2 values

Tags: c#, sorting

i have a list two values.
i want to sort out with priority 1x first.
if x1 was big so sort x1 up and if x1 equal big with x1 other so sort based on x2 than smallest.

```
public class A
{
    public float x1;
    public float x2;
}

public A(float x1, float x2)
{
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.x2 = x2;
}

List<A> sortedA = new List<A>();

sortedA.Add(new A(5, 1));
sortedA.Add(new A(7, 2));
sortedA.Add(new A(4, 3));
sortedA.Add(new A(2, 4));
```

Example 1

```
x1 - x2
5 - 1
7 - 2
4 - 3
2 - 4
```

The sorted list should print as below:

```
7 - 2
5 - 1
4 - 3
2 - 4
```

Example 2 if x1 equal with x1 other.

```
x1 - x2
5 - 2
3 - 1
7 - 5
7 - 2
```

The sorted list should print as below: if x1 equal with x1 other. Priority x2 Smallest

```
7 - 2
7 - 5
5 - 2
3 - 1
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` methods?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Have a look at implementing IEqualityComparer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: When you have tried OrderBy/ThenBy and the result looks almost right there are also variants for sorting in descending order. Like OrderByDescending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by some comments, `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` or `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending` are probably what you are looking for

```
    using System.Linq;
    List<A> list = new List<A>();

    list.Add(new A(5, 1));
    list.Add(new A(7, 2));
    list.Add(new A(4, 3));
    list.Add(new A(2, 4));
    
    var ordered = list
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.x1)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.x2);
    
    foreach(var val in ordered)
        Console.WriteLine($"{val.x1} - {val.x2}");
```

Output:

[image: result]

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qpkRt8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the List.Sort() method with a custom IComparer implementation to sort the list based on your criteria.

Here's an example implementation of the IComparer class:

```
class CompareA : IComparer<A>
{
    public int Compare(A a1, A a2)
    {
        if (a1.x1 > a2.x1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a1.x1 < a2.x1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (a1.x2 < a2.x2)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a1.x2 > a2.x2)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following code to sort the list:

```
sortedA.Sort(new CompareA());
```

This will sort the list in descending order based on x1, and ascending order based on x2 in case of equal x1 values

Comment: While this will indeed work, it's generally *simpler* to use LINQ and `OrderBy` followed by `ThenBy`, unless in-place sorting is really, really needed.

Comment: I Agree, but knowing multiple options to reach a result isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort existing list, just [Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-sort(system-comparison((-0)))) it; the only thing we have to do is to explain how to compare two items `a` and `b`:

```
sortedA.Sort((a, b) => {
  int order = b.x1.CompareTo(a.x1);

  return order != 0         // if we haven't got tie ...
    ? order                 //   ... return result 
    : a.x2.CompareTo(b.x2); //   on tie compare x2's
});
```

Here we used a simple trick for sorting in *descending* order:

```
b.x1.CompareTo(a.x1) // descending order, note a and b swapped
a.x2.CompareTo(b.x2) // ascending order, business as usual
```